# Regular expression pattern with ? character and characterSequense contains unicode character

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to create regular expression that match Strings whit a-z characters and character for this I write below code:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[a-z\\?]*");
System.out.println(pattern.matcher("*").matches());
System.out.println(pattern.matcher("a").matches());
System.out.println(pattern.matcher("?").matches());
System.out.println(pattern.matcher("汉").matches());
```

And get below output:

```
false
true
true
true
```

I expect defined pattern not match with  "汉" and return false but as you see it return true. Can any one explain the reason of this?

Answer (score 3):

I just tried, and I properly get false true true false. Btw, it is not necessary to escape '?' within brackets. This will just do:

```
            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[a-z?]*");
    System.out.println(pattern.matcher("*").matches());
    System.out.println(pattern.matcher("a").matches());
    System.out.println(pattern.matcher("?").matches());
    System.out.println(pattern.matcher("汉").matches());
```

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure that your editor is saving file with a correct encoding?
I try your test saving file as UTF-8 or UTF-16 and both cases return me: false, true, true, false.

Comment: thank you very much, I save file as UTF-8 and it work correctly.